# iOSでのJSONを生成する際の構造について

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

以下のような構造のJSONをObjective-Cで生成したいと考えております。

```
{{"category":"picture1","name":"test1"},{"category":"picture2","name":"test2"},....}
```

`{"category":"picture1","name":"test1"}` の部分を一旦配列に入れて JSON にする方法を試したのですが、配列に格納すると以下のように `[]` に囲まれる構造になってしまいます。

```
{[{"category":"picture1","name":"test1"},{"category":"picture2","name":"test2"},....]}
```

冒頭の JSON のような形式にするためには、配列を使用せずに、 NSDictionary の中に NSDictionary を羅列するような構造にすれば良いと思うのですが、やり方が思いつかずに困っております。

これを実現する方法がありましたら、ご教授いただきたく思います。

Comment: NSDictionaryは{key:value}なので想定している構造はできないと思います（外側のNSDictoinaryに格納している要素にkeyが無い）。

Comment: ですよね。。ありがとうございますm(_)m

Comment: そもそもJSONとして正しくないですよ。次のように一番外側は配列なのではありませんか？
[{"category":"picture1","name":"test1"},{"category":"picture2","name":"test2"}, ...]